# Stored Procedure updating all rows not just a single row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that for some reason works except it is updating ALL rows within the table and not limiting to the unique identifier - can anyone suggest why?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_location`(
 IN UID CHAR(17),
 IN lat FLOAT(10,6),
 IN lng FLOAT(10,6),
 IN country VARCHAR(3)
)
 BEGIN
 UPDATE location 
 SET lat = lat, lng = lng, country = country 
 WHERE UID = UID;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different names for parameters:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_location`(
 IN p_UID CHAR(17),
 IN p_lat FLOAT(10,6),
 IN p_lng FLOAT(10,6),
 IN p_country VARCHAR(3)
)
 BEGIN
 UPDATE location 
 SET lat = p_lat,
     lng = p_lng,
     country = p_country 
 WHERE UID = p_UID;
END
```

Original `WHERE UID = UID` is always true, like `1=1`.

Comment: perfect simple and effective